# init.d script : how to stop all process tree with start-stop-daemon

Tags: debian, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I made an init.d script that don't stop properly the service i run:

```
start() {
    echo "Starting Server"
    rm -f $LOGFILE
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --chuid $USER:$GROUP --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --chdir $PATH --startas /bin/bash -- -c "exec $BIN -f $CONFIG | gawk -E $FILTER > $LOGFILE"
}

stop() {
    echo "Stopping Server"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE
}
```

starting the service create a process tree and stop() kills only the shell and not the main process $BIN
I tried a lot of things like making a wrapper script etc and still the same problem..
i need to use PID because i want to lanch multiple instances of the service

Anyone knows the proper way ?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Debian? If it is 8, you should use systemd, not sysv init scripts.

Comment: Debian 7 (Wheezy) (64 bits)

Answer (score -1):

Your service should create `pidfile` for daemon to kill.
The `--make-pidfile` option shoud be removed